# Show field details in apex page

Tags: apex, visualforce, pageblocktable, table

I have below code where I need to show selected object's fields along with it's API Name, Label, Length, Type in a table format.

Can someone please let me know if I can do that using fieldpropertiesmap in below code?

```
    public void getFieldsPicklist(){
        toShowFields=true;

        fieldsOpt = new list<selectoption>();
        fieldsOpt.add(new selectoption('--NONE--','--NONE--'));
        jsondata = '[{';
        Map <String, schema.describefieldresult> fieldPropertiesMap;

        fieldMap = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(selectedObject).getDescribe().fields.getMap();
        fieldPropertiesMap = new Map <String, schema.describefieldresult> ();

        system.debug('fieldMap='+fieldMap.keySet());
        system.debug('fieldMap='+fieldMap.values());
        // List<Schema.SObjectField> fieldschema = new List<Schema.SObjectField>();
        List<Schema.SObjectField> fieldschema = new List<Schema.SObjectField>();
        for(Schema.SObjectField sfield : fieldMap.Values()) {
            schema.describefieldresult dfield = sfield.getDescribe();
            fieldsOpt.add(new selectoption(dfield.getname(),dfield.getname()));
            fieldPropertiesMap.put(dfield.getName(), dfield);
            fieldschema.add(sfield);
            system.debug('Name'+dfield.getName());
            system.debug('Label'+dfield.getLabel());
            system.debug('Length'+dfield.getLength());
            system.debug('Nill'+dfield.isNillable());
            system.debug('Type'+dfield.getType());
            system.debug('Unique'+dfield.isUnique());

        }
    }
```

Comment: What issue are you having with this code? `fieldPropertiesMap` appears to simply map from field API name to the `DescribeFieldResult`. The latter object is what you need to obtain the field details you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apex Code

```
public class TestStackDev {
public String selectedOpt{get;set;}

//wrapper class
    class Data{
        public String name {get;set;}
        public String lable {get; set;}
        public String length {get;set;}
        public String Nill {get;set;}
        public String type {get;set;}
        public String unique {get;set;}     
    }
    public List<Data> getFieldsPicklist(){

        //return if there is no such object
        if(Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(selectedOpt) == null){return null;}

        Map<String, schema.describefieldresult> fieldPropertiesMap = new Map <String, schema.describefieldresult> ();

        Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(selectedOpt).getDescribe().fields.getMap();


        List<Schema.SObjectField> fieldschema = new List<Schema.SObjectField>();

        List<Data> result = new List<Data>();
        for(Schema.SObjectField sfield : fieldMap.Values()) {

            schema.describefieldresult dfield = sfield.getDescribe();

            Data t = new Data();
            t.name  = dfield.getName();
            t.lable = dfield.getLabel();
            t.length = '' + dfield.getLength();
            t.Nill = dfield.isNillable()? 'TRUE': 'FALSE';
            t.type = '' + dfield.getType();
            t.unique = dfield.isUnique()? 'TRUE' : 'FALSE';
            result.add(t);

        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Visual force Page

```
<apex:page  controller = "TestStackDev">

    <apex:pageBlock title="Hello {!$User.FirstName}!">
        <apex:form>
            <apex:actionFunction reRender="thePanels" name="yourFunction"/>
            <apex:selectList id="chooseColor" value="{!selectedOpt}" size="1" onchange="yourFunction()">

                <apex:selectOption itemValue="None" itemLabel="None"/>
                <apex:selectOption itemValue="User" itemLabel="Users"/>
                <apex:selectOption itemValue="Account" itemLabel="Accounts"/>

            </apex:selectList> 
        </apex:form>
    </apex:pageBlock>
    <apex:pageBlock title="Fields">

        <apex:pageBlockTable id="thePanels" value="{!FieldsPicklist}" var="item" rendered="true">

            <apex:column value="{!item.name}" headerValue="Name" />
            <apex:column value="{!item.lable}" headerValue="Lable" />
            <apex:column value="{!item.length}" headerValue="Length" />
            <apex:column value="{!item.Nill}" headerValue="Nill" />
            <apex:column value="{!item.unique}" headerValue="Unique" />

        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock> 

</apex:page>
```

Screenshot

[image]

Comment: Thanks @pranav! This gets me compiled fine but getting this error when selecting the sobject. Return type of an Apex action method must be a PageReference. Found: core.apexpages.el.adapters.ApexListELAdapter

Comment: @Testing_SFDC well its working for me on API version from 39 to 43.
Make sure you've copied the code safely.